# Node server is not starting

Tags: node.js, http

```
const http = require('http');

const server = http.createServer((res, req) => {
    res.write("Welcome to our home page");
    res.end();

})

server.listen(5000);
```

I compiled the code using `node filename.js`. However it is showing `res.write()`is not a function. At times the error is not showing until I try to access the `localhost`.

Comment: I would suggest going with the express framework, as making web servers are much easier. [This](https://github.com/undevable/rocket) is a library on Github I made which you can use that includes already a fully functional express web server.

Answer (score 5):

You flipped the parameters - `req` (request) goes first:

```js
const server = http.createServer((req, res) => {
    res.write("Welcome to our home page");
    res.end();
});
```